# `python manage.py runserver` will termination in the remote server.

Tags: python, django

Whether the `runserver` have time limit?

In my remote server virtual environment, I use runserver command to start my development server(by my Mac, my Mac use ssh connected to the remote server) :

```
(venv)$ python3 manage.py runserver 183.97.12.26:8001
```

and after scores of minutes, it will broken up by itself, if I do not use my Mac(my Mac maybe dormancy).

So, how can I make it do not break off.

Who can tell me the issue is cause by the command or by the virtualenv?

Comment: Why are you developing on a remote server, rather than on your Mac?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Not your thinking. I put the code to remote server, just there can be  a public ip/ or domain to shows the api and website. some one if want to see that.

Comment: Ok, then why are you using the development server?

Comment: Because I will often modify it. do you mean I can also use distribute server if I want to modify my code?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What does frequent modification have to do with which server you use?

Comment: I am sorry about it, I mean whether make django to distribution( mod_wsgi), not the runserver (development) .